# graphics card error on dual boot with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, graphics

So I dual-booted with Windows 7 and this is my first time ever using Ubuntu.

As soon as I start Ubuntu it gives me this image and I don't understand what is happening.  I think this a graphics card error, it works on Windows 7.

Also it occasionaly gives me an option to run graphics in low settings. I do it but it still doesn't work, I usually just get a purple screen with black and green bars.

I have a custom computer:

- Nvidia GTX 760
- Intel core i5 4670k
- Gigabyte z87-hd3 motherboard

I also have 2 hard drives and the SSD is for Windows and the 1 TB WD is for Ubuntu. I partitioned it so only about 150 GB are for Ubuntu.

Comment: where is the image? also what drivers you are using for the graphics card? proprietary or free?

Comment: Well I couldn't even download the drivers cause I didn't even get into the Ubuntu desktop but in windows I use the free ones

Comment: did the LiveCD or USB worked? If it does please copy the output of `lspci | grep video`. For opening the terminal in the grafical interface just press Ctrl + Alt + T.

Answer (score -1):

Paste into a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319
```

press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Please consider asking the OP for more details about the problem before suggesting to install a unstable PPA.

Comment: How do I get to the terminal ctrl alt f1?

Comment: @Massin No, Ctrl + Alt + T

Comment: Terminal does not want to open that's the problem